# An error occurred while installing byebug (8.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, byebug

I try to run 'bundle install' but i have this problem with byebug gem. 
This is my setup 
rails 4.2.2 
ruby 2.3.1 with rbenv 
Mac OS 11.6.2 
Thanks for your support
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
.
.
.
Using bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails 0.1.5
Using bootstrap-switch-rails 3.3.2
Using browser 2.4.0
Using uniform_notifier 1.10.0
Using bullet 5.6.0
Fetching byebug 8.2.1
Installing byebug 8.2.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-8.2.1/ext/byebug
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20220426-5932-1nggi5e.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-8.2.1/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-8.2.1/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR="
compiling locker.c
compiling byebug.c
byebug.c:198:27: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_line"), 0, Qnil);

/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1722:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
byebug.c:204:27: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_tracing"), 0, Qnil);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1727:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
byebug.c:204:27: note: ')' token is here
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_tracing"), 0, Qnil);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
 
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
byebug.c:212:27: note: '{' token is here
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_breakpoint"), 1, breakpoint);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1722:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
byebug.c:212:27: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_breakpoint"), 1, breakpoint);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1727:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
byebug.c:212:27: note: ')' token is here
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_breakpoint"), 1, breakpoint);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
byebug.c:220:27: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_catchpoint"), 1, exp);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
byebug.c:220:27: note: '{' token is here
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_catchpoint"), 1, exp);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1722:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
byebug.c:220:27: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_catchpoint"), 1, exp);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1727:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
byebug.c:220:27: note: ')' token is here
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_catchpoint"), 1, exp);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
byebug.c:228:27: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_return"), 1, return_value);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
byebug.c:228:27: note: '{' token is here
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_return"), 1, return_value);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1722:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
byebug.c:228:27: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_return"), 1, return_value);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1727:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
byebug.c:228:27: note: ')' token is here
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_return"), 1, return_value);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
byebug.c:236:27: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_end"), 0, Qnil);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
byebug.c:236:27: note: '{' token is here
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_end"), 0, Qnil);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1722:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
byebug.c:236:27: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_end"), 0, Qnil);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1727:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
byebug.c:236:27: note: ')' token is here
  return call_at(ctx, dc, rb_intern("at_end"), 0, Qnil);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
byebug.c:442:35: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
    rb_ivar_set(raised_exception, rb_intern("@__bb_context"), pm_context);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
byebug.c:442:35: note: '{' token is here
    rb_ivar_set(raised_exception, rb_intern("@__bb_context"), pm_context);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1722:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
byebug.c:442:35: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
    rb_ivar_set(raised_exception, rb_intern("@__bb_context"), pm_context);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1727:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
byebug.c:442:35: note: ')' token is here
    rb_ivar_set(raised_exception, rb_intern("@__bb_context"), pm_context);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
byebug.c:560:33: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  list = rb_funcall(rb_cThread, rb_intern("list"), 0);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
byebug.c:560:33: note: '{' token is here
  list = rb_funcall(rb_cThread, rb_intern("list"), 0);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1722:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
byebug.c:560:33: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  list = rb_funcall(rb_cThread, rb_intern("list"), 0);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1727:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
byebug.c:560:33: note: ')' token is here
  list = rb_funcall(rb_cThread, rb_intern("list"), 0);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:51: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                  ^
byebug.c:900:12: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts
[-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  idPuts = rb_intern("puts");
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \

/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1737:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1730:37: note: expanded from macro 'CONST_ID_CACHE'
#define CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str) RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE(result, str)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:1722:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [byebug.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-8.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-20/2.3.0-static/byebug-8.2.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing byebug (8.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '8.2.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  pry-byebug was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
    byebug
```

Comment: I think the best first step would be to follow the suggestion near the end of the output:

Try running `gem install byebug -v '8.2.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` and see if you can install it independently. You may get different or more helpful error output.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me: 1) run sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools xcode-select --install 2 ) xcode-select --install 3) brew install llvm 4 ) export CC=clang. see this post: github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/280